# AntiXSS - HtmlAttributeEncode usage

Tags: asp.net, xss, antixsslibrary

I am trying to figure out the context in which HtmlAttributeEncode could be used -

I tried with simple 'Hello!' alert script to be set as control attribute, so I could see HtmlAttributeEncode in action - but can't see where I can use HtmlAttributeEncode instead of HtmlEncode.

So, for example, I have

```
- a textbox for user input 
  //txtuserInput.Text = <script>alert(document.cookie);</script>

- an anchor control to show user input being set as one of its attribute value 
  In codebehind tried with - 
     myanchorTag.InnerText = txtuserInput.Text
     or
     myanchorTag.Id = txtuserInput.Text
```

But I can't see this script running :-(
I have already tried that for TextBox.Text property but for that I can use HtmlEncode.

Can anyone please guide.

Thank you!

Comment: what asp.net version you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asp:Textbox control automatically escapes the .Text property. See http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-components-postattachments/00-08-91-89-96/asp.net_5F00_control_5F00_encoding.htm

You should use HtmlAttributeEncode when using unescaped controls and when building raw html.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing this list - makes things more clear. But I am still not very clear about HtmlAttributeEncode usage. When you say raw html, did you mean creating control at run-time like 'new HyperLink() { Text = Encoder.HtmlEncode(txtUserInput.Text) }. I tried with some other control and couldn't find any difference in using HtmlEncode and HtmlAttributeEncode. Did you mean something else for 'raw html'? Can you please give a good usage of HtmlAttributeEncode.

Comment: Lets say you have one of these:

Comment: <a title='<asp:Literal ID="Link" runat="server" />'> or <a id="Link" runat="server">. In both of these cases if you want to set the title attribute you shoul html attribute encode it. What I meant by raw html is if you are building html by concatenating strings and then output the entire thing in a literal or something like that.

Comment: If you want to see why attribute encoding is needed remember that for attributes can be quote with several different kinds of quotes. See the Owasp xss prevention cheat sheet and www.insecurelabs.org/Task/